# Lit: nested template doesn't render

Tags: web-component, lit-element, parceljs, lit-html, lit

I have a really simple template and a simple nested template. Unfortunately, my nested template doesn't render anything.

I followed the example defined at: https://lit.dev/docs/components/rendering/

This is my container template.

```
import "./ul-mail";

@customElement("box-mail")
class BoxMail extends LitElement {
  public render() {
    return html`
      <div>
        <ul-mail></ul-mail>
        <p>custom</p> 
      </div>
    `;
  }
}
```

this is my nested template.

```
@customElement("ul-mail")
class UlMail extends LitElement {

  connectedCallback(): void {
    console.log("UL-MAIL CHILD: connected now"); // triggers.
  }

  public render() {
    console.log("UL-MAIL CHILD: rendered"); // doesn't trigger.
    return html`<p>hello from ul-mail!</p>`;
  }
}
```

My page looks like this in the devtools inspector:

```html
<box-mail>
 #shadow-root(open)
 <!---->
 <div>
   <ul-mail><ul-mail>
   <p>custom</p>
 </div>
</box-mail>
```

As you can see; `ul-mail` renders nothing, no `hello from ul-mail!`.

I was wondering what is going wrong?

Comment: I don't know Lit, lucky enough to not have to. In vanilla JS your code would need a ``super.connectedCallback()`` inside your own ``connectedCallback`` where (I think) Lit triggers the ``render`` method.. That is exaclty why I say _Learn the Technology first, and the Tools later_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anytime we implement lifecycle callback methods, it's necessary to call the parent class's methods (so the superclass features work as-expected).

> If you need to customize any of the standard custom element lifecycle methods, make sure to call the super implementation (such as super.connectedCallback()) so the standard Lit functionality is maintained.
>
> [Standard custom element lifecycle](https://lit.dev/docs/components/lifecycle/#custom-element-lifecycle)

```
  connectedCallback(): void {
    super.connectedCallback()
    console.log("UL-MAIL CHILD: connected now"); // triggers.
  }
```